# "The Queen" in French

Tags: traduction

The queen in England is called "The Queen", but how do you translate this into French? What I read in the dictionary is confusing. Please keep the answer simple as I'm not fluent in English (and not in French either).

Comment: Have you looked in a [dictionary](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/queen)? If so, why wasn't the answer satisfactory? Are you asking whether *The* Queen would be different than *a* queen?

Comment: Isn't The Queen different from a quuen?

Comment: The Queen of England is a queen among others in the world, but linguistically speaking, a queen is a queen is a queen; you capitalize the first letter when talking about a particular person but the word remains the same. Were you asking if it would be two different words in French? If so, why would you think that? Did you look for the answer in a dictionary and find yourself confused by the information written there?

Comment: I really was confused by the dictionary. That's why I came here.

Comment: Right, then if you could please include in your questions what you were looking for, what you found, how you don't understand it, it would really help us provide you with a better answer and show that you also made an effort. As your question stands, it appears that you have made no research effort and are asking a question that seems to be easily answered by opening a dictionary (but it didn't for you, so you need to tell us). Writing detailed questions on StackExchange will help you get better  answers. :)

Comment: By the way, in English it looks like it's "the Queen", not "The Queen" - see for example http://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2015/dec/25/queen-christmas-message-light-darkness-tv-broadcast

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. Sorry but I have to translate every word is said to Dutch (my language) and since I'm still a child, it's really hard because everyone always uses difficul words.

Comment: How old are you?

Comment: 14 years old, so my second year I learn English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *La Reine* (of England, which is evident in England) or *La Reine d'Angleterre*,

like *The President* is *Le Président* (in France):

- in political context in France: *Le Président* (shorter), or *Le Président de la République* (more formal), or *Le Président français*, or *Le Président (François) Hollande*.
- in other contexts in France: *Le Président de la République* when it is not evident (because there are thousands of presidents, almost every organization has one or several).
- in foreign countries, we can hear (depends on journalists) *Le Président français*, *Le Président de la République française*, *Le Président Hollande*.